# Getting my images in css to work on rails and asset pipeline with upgraded app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

This is an app that I am upgrading to Rails 3.1, along with the asset pipeline. Everything looks peachy in development, but when I push to heroku, the images in my css are not displaying.

Couple of questions. First, should I leave these files with the css extention, or should they be renamed to either scss, or css.scss.erb?

The other question I have is how should I reference images in the css. Currently I have...

```
  background: #B4F4FF url(/assets/img01.jpg) repeat-x left top;^M
```

I am pretty sure I need to replace url with either 'image_tag' or 'asset_tag'...looks like there are a few options available. Also, what should the path be?...../assets, assets/images, just the file name???

I've tried all manner of methods, and paths, and can't get this to work in Heroku. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow! This was a real pain to figure out.

For me the issue centered around static pages that I had in my app. I had to add the line...

```
  config.assets.precompile += ['static_pages.css']
```

to config/environments/production.rb, then compile my assets locally with

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

then push all that to heroku.

Comment: This worked for me too, with the exception that there was a line in production (commented out).. config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )